# How can I get direct live feed (data) from my website (server) to my android app as push notifications?

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I don't want to manually push data for each notifications via parse push notifications or GCM. As soon as there is a change in website (for example if a user posts something, notification should be pushed to all devices having android app), a push notification is sent to all devices regarding that.

Further details : 
Similar to a news app, where when a new blog is posted on website, the android app get the notification automatically.

Comment: Check out WebSockets, or MQTT, STOMP or HTTP long polling

Comment: Can you please give a link to an example, showing implementation in android programming.